# SwiftUI - Section style difference when embedding List within a VStack

Tags: ios, swiftui

It seems that there is a difference in showing a `List` `Section` header when you embed the List in a `VStack`. Does anybody know why this happens?

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var toggle: Bool = false

let items: [String] = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        if toggle {
            VStack {
                list
            }
        } else {
            list
        }
    }
    
}

var list: some View {
    List {
        Section {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        } header: {
            Text("Fruit")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle(toggle ? "VStack" : "No VStack")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button {
                toggle.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: List knows is parent is NavigationView and apply different style.

Comment: @Asperi both Lists have the NavigationView as parent here.

Comment: You can apply specific style as per your needs i.e. .listStyle(.grouped) or .listStyle(.sidebar). .automatic is default